# Why does Big Endian end with the little byte?

Tags: byte, terminology

It is common to say that the "end" of a memory (or a memory segment) has the highest address. For example: Program Counters are typically incremented (not decremented) and the code is executed from "start" to "end", so the instruction at the end of the program is located at the highest address (not the lowest one).

The **Big**Endian convention specifies that the **biggest** byte (i.e. the most significant byte) is located at the lowest address (i.e. the start of the memory). Shouldn't it be the other way around? It's Big**End**ian, not Big**Start**ian.

Similarly LittleEndian specifies that the smallest byte is located at the start of the memory instead of at the end.

Why is it backwards?

Comment: I think that thinking of the most-significant byte as the "biggest" byte is giving you the issue. [The term comes from Gulliver's Travels](http://www.faircom.com/ace/enl_21_endian_t.php), not from the "biggest" byte being at the end in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the illustrious [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness):

> In 1726, Jonathan Swift described in his satirical novel Gulliver’s
>   Travels tensions in Lilliput and Blefuscu: whereas royal edict in
>   Lilliput requires cracking open one's soft-boiled egg at the small
>   end, inhabitants of the rival kingdom of Blefuscu crack theirs at the
>   big end, giving them the moniker Big-endians. The terms little-endian
>   and endianness have a similar intent.

So if we look at it in this context, an x-endian is he who begins at the x end. Thus, a big-endian is he who begins at the "big" end, so to speak, of a value, and vice versa.

Comment: Now that's an explanation of that article I can understand. "To start at the big end" makes sense. However I still think that BigEndian and LittleEndian could be worded better.

Comment: You're probably right, but we're stuck with it now. :) Glad I could shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

It's using "end" to mean "adjacent to an extremity", just like:

- You burn a candle at both ends, not at the start and at the end.
- A loaf of bread has two end pieces, but no start piece.
- You can be seated at opposite ends of a table, but not at the start and end.

A number like 1234567 has two ends, and you can store either the big end (a million) or the little end (seven) first.